# Is it possible to have a "Time" Schema in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know I can do `Date`. but what about Time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to get created at/updated at timestamps? If so you can use [mongoose-types](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-types#readme) to add that as a plugin. Or you could use a mixed type I suppose.